# Build Xamarin.iOS for simulator from command line

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, msbuild, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.uitest

When you build a Xamarin.iOS project for simulator from the Visual Studio for Mac it creates an `.app` file in `YourApp.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone12.1-13.2.2/` directory and deploys it to a simulator. You also can install the .app file on a simulator manually.

However, it works only from the VS4Mac UI.

When I'm trying to build the project via `msbuild` from my Terminal it does not generate the artifacts.

From the console logs, I can see that MSBuild spets (build targets output) does not match with the Build Output in the VS4Mac.

Is there a way to achieve the same result (built `YourApp.app` file) but through a command line?

*P.S. What I really trying to achieve is to build the `.app` simulator bundle on a custom pre-build step of my Xamarin.UITest project, so it could launch the app on a simulator and run tests.*

Comment: Hi , if want to [Customizing the IPA Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows#customizing-the-ipa-location) by MSBuild , you can have a look at this .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
msbuild -restore iosproject.csproj -p:Configuration=Release -p:OutputPath=/youroutputpath
```

Comment: Add `-p:Platform=iPhoneSimulator` to target the iOS simulator